# Stripe doesn't work after deploying on Heroku by Django

Tags: python, django, heroku, stripe-payments

*English is not my mother language,so if my English is not correct,please ignore.

At Local, Stripe has worked well on Django.
But after deploying Heroku, Stripe(subscription Service) doesn't work. When I click "Pay",everytime showed " Internet Error 500".I checked Heroku logs,but connect and service looks like okay.

I've tried deployed again and again, but everytime the results are same. Showing "Internet Error 500".

This is logs by Heroku logs --tail

```
2024-03-19T08:03:27.576123+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/checkout/" host=nagoyameshi-marina-32890ff7fdd2.herokuapp.com request_id=40d9d9e5-8ebf-436f-9254-2e862dcada7e fwd="126.15.11.7" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=19ms status=500 bytes=459 protocol=https
2024-03-19T08:03:27.576163+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.20.255 - - [19/Mar/2024:17:03:27 +0900] "POST /checkout/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "https://nagoyameshi-marina-32890ff7fdd2.herokuapp.com/terms_of_service/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

These are my settings.py and CheckoutView from views.py I deployed on Heroku.

```
    if "STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY" in os.environ and "STRIPE_API_KEY" in os.environ and "STRIPE_PRICE_ID" in os.environ:
    STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY  = os.environ["STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY"]
    STRIPE_API_KEY          = os.environ["STRIPE_API_KEY"]
    STRIPE_PRICE_ID         = os.environ["STRIPE_PRICE_ID"]

 - CheckoutView
stripe.api_key  = settings.STRIPE_API_KEY
```

```
class CheckoutView(LoginRequiredMixin,View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        checkout_session =stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            line_items=[
                {
                    'price':settings.STRIPE_PRICE_ID,
                    'quantity':1,
                },
            ],
            payment_method_types=['card'],
            mode='subscription',
            success_url=request.build_absolute_uri(reverse_lazy("nagoyameshi:success")) + '?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
            cancel_url=request.build_absolute_uri(reverse_lazy("nagoyameshi:index")),
        )

print( checkout_session["id"] )
return redirect(checkout_session.url)

checkout    = CheckoutView.as_view()
```

DB is " Heroku Postgres".

Comment: It's hard to tell just by looking at your code. You would want to debug by adding logs on your backend function. ie. does it load all the environment variables correctly (common issue for local vs. hosting provider)? Does it work if you remove the `stripe.checkout.Session.create` code? Try to locate the full stacktrace on Heroku would help too.

Comment: @orakaro Thanks for replying. I've chechked  all the environment variables, but these are correct. I've never tried stripe.checkout.Session.create,so I try this code first. Again,thank you for your replying!

Comment: @orakaro I've already tried stripe.checkout.Session.create code on CheckoutView of views.py.

Comment: Yes but your function is returning 500, so you would want to see where does it stuck. If you insert some log before the call to `stripe.checout.Session.create`, does it get outputted to your Heroku server log?

Comment: @orakaro I actuially solved this problem! Thank you for your cooperation.